# htaccess redirect folder to new domain index only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have looked and looked and cant find the answer, I would greatly appreciate your help!!

I designed a website in a folder on a dummy domain, and forgot to add "noindex" and now its indexed, I need to redirect all pages in that folder to the index of the new domain.
example:
http: //dummysite/clientsfolder/
(I had to put space here because I can't post 2 links)

redirect to http://clientsnewdomain.com

all the code I have found redirects to http ://clientsnewdomain.com/clients folder, whether I place it in the /clientsfolder or the http://dummysite/
and then this results in a 404 page. Got into a mess here.

Also which is better to use to avoid this issue in the first place?
in  
or a robots.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Use that, in your `/clientsfolder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://clientsnewdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

OR in the root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^clientsfolder/(.*)$ http://clientsnewdomain.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

The best place to avoid this issue in the first place is to use robots.txt.
But I prefer to use a folder protected by a password.